# The line 56 in the file /etc/apt/ sources.list is not correct (URI parse)

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-sources

Kubuntu doesn't let me upgrade. The error message says:

```
The line 56 in the file /etc/apt/sources.list is not correct (URI parse)
```

Comment: Could you please translate the error message to English?

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue that was solved in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2097047)

1.) Lets make a backup:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.old
```

2.) What this means is that the source list could have an issue on line 56.

```
sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list | grep 56
```

3.) look for the line created by 2 and maybe comment comment it out with a "#"

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

4.) and then update

`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: thanks ,do you suggest to make all the 4ways or those re 4 possibility?

Comment: What have you done so far?
Are you still getting the error?

Comment: #  :~$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo: gedit: comando non trovato

Comment: shuold be °getit°?

Comment: or your text editor?   `sudo nano`, `sudo kate`

Comment: and .. ~$ sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list | grep 56
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: File o directory non esistente

Comment: If you could please find where your `sources.list` file is and post it here in a code block it will be easier for me to understand.

Comment: ok thanks jmu x helpin me! but in my first ..message ,doesn't appeare ,but i'd wrote that im pretty ignare about konsolle ..scriptin etc..so please if u can get me a comand ?

Comment: I do not have enough information to help you. 
Please post this info.
`lsb_release -a`

Comment: x exemple what u mean whit my text editor?   So first please how can i find&make this? :where your sources.list file is and post it here in a code block.

Comment: open terminal [like this](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/images/terminalgnomeprecise.jpg) ... [or this](http://www.chrisabney.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/1.png)


and run 

`sudo lsb_release -a`

and post your results here.

Comment: What language do you speak?

Comment: assuming that you speak Italian here is a google translation ...

Aprire sources.list con l'editor di testo. Guardate la linea 56. Si sta causando un problema. Vorrei vedere quale distribuzione si sta utilizzando. Si prega di mostrare i risultati di `lsb_release -a`

Comment: sorry i was nt refreshin t page ,english its bet than traslator

Comment: LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-ia32:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-ia32:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy

Comment: lets find sources.list by using this command in terminal :

`locate sources.list -i `

Navigate to where the file is located and edit line 56. (ex. /etc/apt/sources.list ) By using your preferred text editor (gedit, nano, vi, vim, emacs, kate ....) comment out line 56 by adding "#" to the start of the line 

( #deb http://someaddress.com/some_dist/etc )

Comment: this s the result x the command /etc/apt/sources.list......

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth.list.save
/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list
/usr/share/man/de/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/es/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man5/sources.list.5.gz
/usr/share/man/pt/man5/sources.list.5.gz

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/info/kdepim-kresources.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pkg-resources.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-pkg-resources.list

Comment: sorry this is t result of the command u d wrote me ,its all i know do ..that i understand.

Comment: what does line 56 of this look like? `sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list`  should show the lines of the file with the numbers on the left side?

Comment: i d wrote again t command: locate sources.list -i ..added by t nr 56 ,but results a lot of 56line .

Comment: This is a different command for terminal : `sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list` Can you please share the results of this?

Comment: cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: File o directory non esistente
  ..but before i d put t number on the right side ..now i will try to the left.

Comment: You should be able to copy `sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list` into the terminal and it should give us a bunch of lines with numbers next to them. We are looking for line 56.

Comment: venusion@venusion-900HD:~$ sudo cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list
[sudo] password for venusion: 
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: File o directory non esistente
venusion@venusion-900HD:~$

Comment: non esistente=not existing file

Comment: so looks than i dont have a sources-list ..superable problem.

Comment: @jmunsch in your command you moved the sources.list file. Of course he will not find it again..

Comment: @venionus use `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.old  /etc/apt/sources.list` and try again.

Comment: @Braiam thanks for catching this sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that there is some problem in the line 56 of your sources.list, I bet you can remove it without problem:

```
sudo sed -i.bak -e '56d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```